# Can't find UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR anywhere

Tags: ios, uiappearance

iOS documentation of `UIAppearanceContainer` Protocol Reference says:

> "To participate in the appearance proxy API, tag your appearance
>   property accessor methods in your header with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR."

But when I, for example, open UIButton.h, I can't find anywhere `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`, although I can use something like this wihout problems:

```
    [[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"UIButton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on :D ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find it because the accessor is inherited from `UIView` (`UIButton` inherits from; `UIControl` : `UIView` : `UIResponder` : `NSObject`).
So when you're doing `[UIButton appearance]` you get the appearance proxy for the passed class, just because `UIView` adopts the `UIAppearance` and `UIAppearanceContainer` protocols. I hope that this makes sense.

PS. If you look for example `UIBarButtonItem`'s header file, you will see that the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` is there.

Comment: in UIView there aren't property for backgroundImage e there aren't property flagged with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR

Comment: @Alladinian: Thanks, that's it :) I've found it inside UIBarButtonItem's header file :)

Answer (score 2):

`-[UIButton setBackgroundImage:resizableImageWithCapInsets:]` Is not a property but is a method. Therefor the quote from Apple documentation is still valid.

UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR is a simple #define and I suppose is only an hint for the compiler to do some special stuff with a @property.

Comment: UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTED is simple #define to nothing, but as far as I've understood the docs, it should be there to let the users know which methods they can and which they can not use with appearance proxy.